# Rails App won't Push on Heroku - Tilt gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile, tilt

This is what my Gemfile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'heroku'
gem 'tilt'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
group :development do
  gem 'taps'
  gem 'rvm'
end
```

This is what my Gemfile.lock file looks like:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
    activesupport (3.2.12)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.3)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    excon (0.16.10)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    heroku (2.35.0)
      heroku-api (~> 0.3.7)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      netrc (~> 0.7.7)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip
    heroku-api (0.3.8)
      excon (~> 0.16.10)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.7)
    kgio (2.8.0)
    launchy (2.2.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    libv8 (3.11.8.13)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.21)
    multi_json (1.6.1)
    netrc (0.7.7)
    pg (0.14.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.12)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      activerecord (= 3.2.12)
      activeresource (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.12)
    railties (3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.10.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.2)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.6)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    therubyracer (0.11.4)
      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
      ref
    thor (0.17.0)
    tilt (1.3.5)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.36)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.6.2)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  execjs
  heroku
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.12)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  therubyracer
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  unicorn
```

When I run:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 90, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
Writing objects: 100% (90/90), 31.71 KiB, done.
Total 90 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find tilt-1.3.5 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:xxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:xxxxx.git'
```

Things I've tried to fix it:

- $bundle install tilt
- $bundle update
- deleted .git and $git init
- deleted gemfile.lock and did $bundle install again
- logged in and out of heroku
- restarted computer
- followed instructions on [Heroku for Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3), [Rails Apps](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html), and searched thru all the stackoverflow questions regarding heroku and rails and made the changes to my code it suggestested. (The questions were usually about sqlite databases, but I've already resolved that issue.)
- prayed
- cried

...And none of it has worked. I've been troubleshooting non-stop for the last two days. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a problem with the newer version of tilt. In your Gemfile try specifying

```
gem 'tilt', '1.3.4'
```

Comment: Perfect! worked like a charm. :-)

I updated the Gemfile with that line, then had to update the version of tilt in Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

I have done so

`rm Gemfile.lock` and do `bundle install` , (!) then `git add .`, `git commit` and `git push` .